# multi selection in Form list with return and add line

Tags: jquery, list, select, drop-down-menu

*emphasized text*Ok its little be hard to explain , i will try ;)

the user need to create a name , by example the name is "AMAZON" ..IN the name he can "defined" multi select object ... 
so by example Amazon can be :

> Amazone =

1. Front + 100x100 + Black + PNG
2. Left + 256*256 + red + jpg
3. *ADD LINE +*

> SAVE

so i need save line IN Amazone and add multiple Line ..& after the user can save All

( See here http://www.nanosix.be/test/form.html )

I am lost i think i need javascript ...

any idea how to do that's ?

**EDIT SOLUTION: https://jsfiddle.net/d8gf7n7u/17/** 
*( Just the last problem the shortlink button duplicate all "line", not just the original line and if i click on add he duplicate every where)*

```
                <h2>VRi SHORT LINK Configurator</h2>
            <form method="post" action="" method="get">

                <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name"   >
                <br>
                <br>

                <form action="" class="multichoix">
                    <select name="View">
                      <option value="none">View</option>
                      <option value="front">Front</option>
                      <option value="right">Right</option>
                      <option value="left">Left</option>
                      <option value="bottom">Bottom</option>
                      <option value="free">Camera Free</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name="Size" >
                      <option value="none">Size</option>
                      <option value="">Web HD (1980*1024)</option>
                      <option value="">web (800*600)</option>
                      <option value="">Poster A2</option>
                      <option value="">Poster A1</option>
                      <option value="">Page A4</option>
                      <option value="">Flyer A5</option>
                      <option value="">Flyer A5</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name="Color">
                      <option value="none">Background</option>
                      <option value="">Transparent</option>
                      <option value="">Black</option>
                      <option value="">White</option>
                      <option value="">Orange</option>
                      <option value="">grey</option>
                    </select>

                    <select name="Format">
                      <option value="none">Format</option>
                      <option value="">PNG</option>
                      <option value="">JPEG</option>
                      <option value="">GIF 360</option>
                      <option value="">Web 360</option>
                    </select>
                </form>

                <button input type="submit" value="Add" class="add">ADD</button>

            <button input type="submit" value="Save">Save</button>

            </form>
```

Jquery :

```
            <script>
                var counter = 1;
                    jQuery('add').click(function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        counter++;
                        var newRow = jQuery('

                            <select name="View">
                              <option value="none">View</option>
                              <option value="front">Front</option>
                              <option value="right">Right</option>
                              <option value="left">Left</option>
                              <option value="bottom">Bottom</option>
                              <option value="free">Camera Free</option>
                            </select>

                            <select name="Size" >
                              <option value="none">Size</option>
                              <option value="">Web HD (1980*1024)</option>
                              <option value="">web (800*600)</option>
                              <option value="">Poster A2</option>
                              <option value="">Poster A1</option>
                              <option value="">Page A4</option>
                              <option value="">Flyer A5</option>
                              <option value="">Flyer A5</option>
                            </select>

                            <select name="Color">
                              <option value="none">Background</option>
                              <option value="">Transparent</option>
                              <option value="">Black</option>
                              <option value="">White</option>
                              <option value="">Orange</option>
                              <option value="">grey</option>
                            </select>

                            <select name="Format">
                              <option value="none">Format</option>
                              <option value="">PNG</option>
                              <option value="">JPEG</option>
                              <option value="">GIF 360</option>
                              <option value="">Web 360</option>
                            </select>');

                        jQuery('.multichoix').append(newRow);
                    });
            </script>
```

Comment: "*so i need save line*", save it where? In a database?

Comment: the Add button need to add a new line & add the line configurate ..after i need a button save for saving "all"

Answer (score 0):

Is anything like this what you need?

https://jsfiddle.net/d8gf7n7u/

```
$("button").on("click", function() {

    var name = $("input").val();
    var view = $("select[name='View']").find('option:selected').text();
    var size = $("select[name='Size']").find('option:selected').text();
    var color = $("select[name='Color']").find('option:selected').text();
    var format = $("select[name='Format']").find('option:selected').text();

    $("form").after("<div class='container'><div class='item'>"+name+"</div><div class='item'>"+view+"</div><div class='item'>"+size+"</div><div class='item'>"+color+"</div><div class='item'>"+format+"</div></div><br>");

});
```

What this do is, it gets the value of the selected options and then it prints them. Not sure what you need to do next with them.

Comment: I love you :D .. there are just a little problem

Comment: How to explain ... ok we can save the value : View size color format IN a name ( thk ! )

but IN a Name i need multi line ..

For understanding : after thats, the user click on a button ( the button name for the example : AMAZON , configurate here )

and he receive a mail with all image  in format "AMAZON" ..

but amazon need multi image not just one .... by example : Front,100*100, jpg, black 

Amazon need,by example, 5 view in 100*100, jpg, black but with front back right etc etc ... so "in" Amazon Format i need to rec multi possibility so when i click on Save button

Comment: By example : http://nanosix.be/test/example.png  . User click on Amazon format and he receive 4 images by mail, ebay 2 image ...but the administrator can configurate the "amazon format" with this form and decide : "amazon format is 4 views in png " ...so he can add a line of configuration IN Amazon format ..i know, it not easy to understand and i don't have a perfect english ^^"

Comment: So, the problem is in the way the information appears? That image you show is what happens after u click save?

Comment: its more like thats : https://jsfiddle.net/d8gf7n7u/24/

but here : i can add line ok , add shortlink ( that copy everything ) but that copy number of line ... and i can add line from the new one ) and i need to delete new one if i want ..pfff ^^ little hard for me

Comment: so i am here : http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/1376/

i always have the same issue i can clone all and add a line but when i clone all i clone my multi line too ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `form` inside a `form`. Instead change the inner form to a `div`. When clicking the "add" button, clone the first div with the class `.multichoix` and insert if after the last `div.multichoix`.

If changed the names of the select as well. I added `[]` to them. After submitting the form, `$_POST['View']` will be an array with the values.

Use `echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo'<pre>';` to see how that works. You'll need to loop those values and add them to your database.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.add').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clone = $('form .multichoix:first-of-type').clone();
    $('form .multichoix:last-of-type').after(clone);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>VRi SHORT LINK Configurator</h2>
<form method="post" action="" method="get">

  <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name">
  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="multichoix">
    <select name="View[]">
      <option value="none">View</option>
      <option value="front">Front</option>
      <option value="right">Right</option>
      <option value="left">Left</option>
      <option value="bottom">Bottom</option>
      <option value="free">Camera Free</option>
    </select>

    <select name="Size[]">
      <option value="none">Size</option>
      <option value="">Web HD (1980*1024)</option>
      <option value="">web (800*600)</option>
      <option value="">Poster A2</option>
      <option value="">Poster A1</option>
      <option value="">Page A4</option>
      <option value="">Flyer A5</option>
      <option value="">Flyer A5</option>
    </select>

    <select name="Color[]">
      <option value="none">Background</option>
      <option value="">Transparent</option>
      <option value="">Black</option>
      <option value="">White</option>
      <option value="">Orange</option>
      <option value="">grey</option>
    </select>

    <select name="Format[]">
      <option value="none">Format</option>
      <option value="">PNG</option>
      <option value="">JPEG</option>
      <option value="">GIF 360</option>
      <option value="">Web 360</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <button input type="submit" value="Add" class="add">ADD</button>

  <button input type="submit" value="Save">Save</button>

</form>
```

Comment: yeps i like thats ..but it's my fault, the button save is not save is add short link so thats need to duplicate all

Comment: something like thats ..Excepte that create only name and not name + the config line 

https://jsfiddle.net/d8gf7n7u/5/

Comment: Just the problem with this solution .. thats clone all line , if we add 4-5 line in the first , that duplicate all line ...

Comment: so i am here : http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/1376/

i always have the same issue i can clone all and add a line but when i clone all i clone my multi line too ...